# pandas: .equals should evaluate to True?

Tags: pandas, equality

I have 2 pandas DataFrames that appear to be exactly the same. However, when I test using the `.equals` method I get `False`. Any idea what the potential inconsistency may be? Is there something I'm not checking?

```
print(df1.values.tolist()==df2.values.tolist())
print(df1.columns.tolist()==df2.columns.tolist())
print(df1.index.tolist()==df2.index.tolist())
print(df1.equals(df2))

# True
# True
# True
# False
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility is different datatypes that evaluate as equal in python-space, e.g.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2.0, 3]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3]})

df1.values.tolist() == df2.values.tolist()
Out[45]: True

df1.equals(df2)
Out[46]: False
```

To chase this down, you can use the `assert_frame_equal` function.

```
from pandas.testing import assert_frame_equal

assert_frame_equal(df1, df2)
AssertionError: Attributes are different

Attribute "dtype" are different
[left]:  float64
[right]: int64
```

In version of pandas before `0.20.1`, the import is `from pandas.util.testing import assert_frame_equal`

Comment: That was it! One column was `int64` while its equivalent was `object`